# java Lists getting class attributes

Tags: java, list, iteration

Im unable to get the mark attribute of Student and dont understand why.

```
public class StudentTest
{
    public static int numberPassed(List students)
    {
        int count =0;
        for( int i = 0; i < students.size();i++  )
        {
        System.out.println(students.get(i).mark);
        }
        return count;
}
```

Comment: `List students` - you erased the type. Every element of the list is treated as `Object`

Comment: Something like `(Student)students.get(i)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ why introduce the overhead of casting?. just use generics in the first place.

Comment: incomplete code. where is 'students' declaration and initiation?

Comment: Student is in the Student class

Comment: how can i access the students mark?

Comment: still returns @Aomine thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, every List holds objects, so operation `list.get(i)` will return an `Object`. If you want to do some action on `Student` class instance, you need to check if this object is a `Student` class instance., then cast it to `Student` class.

If your lists holds only students, you can add a [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) to it like so: `List<Student> stidents`. Then operation `list.get(i)` will return a `Student` instance. But this goes both ways, you can only add `Student` objects to this list.

In short, you have two choices:

Use generic list type:

```
public static int numberPassed(List<Student> students){
      ...
}
```

or cast:

```
Student student = (Student)students.get(i);
System.out.println(student.mark);
```